# External programing of an mcu without Hex

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, microprocessor, control-system, controller

We need to change a controller code from the out side as they do with industrial MCU.
So that you have an MCU, with a program on it, and someone can program some "words" to it, that will determine how it works.

So for example you can program an MCU—not with a programer but with some inputs from serial, to do some simple things such as:

```
if input A==1
b=1
```

I wonder if there is a smart way to do that with simple software on the MCU, that it has many `#defines` for various commands, and it perform them according to values it gets from the outside (and saved for the rest of the program).

I wonder if the industrial programers are using that method, or that every programing of a user is actually load a code (`.hex`) to the chip (with internal programer).

I prefer the simplest way (I wonder if its by pre-defined software).

Comment: Question is confusing, but BASIC STAMP is similar to what you describe. Industrial programming is nearly always the "hex" style, unless it's a PLC which is a different sort of thing.

Comment: It is all done by .hex files. Your way requires an interpreter or compiler running on the 'MCU'. This is commonly the case with personal computers or some devices running linux. What is your application?

Comment: https://github.com/BleuLlama/TinyBasicPlus

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyMite

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: its not for my own comfort, but for a tool that let user put some code into the chip without the programer. for example with IO , set some parameters that will change the way it works .

Comment: for example. how can you tell a mcu to output1 at pinB when pinA is 1 , without having it programmed in the first place, but having in the chip only a general program that can change it self to this .

Comment: The calculator program in Windows is doing what you ask. So are almost all other programs in some way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True microcontrollers only run internal code, and therefore only do what that internal code tells them to do.  That internal code has to get in there somehow.  Modern microcontrollers usually have flash memory where the code is stored, and have special pins that can be wiggled in special ways to write data into that memory.  Devices that connect to a common port on normal computers (like the USB) on one side and connect to said pins on the other side to allow data to be transferred from the computer into the microcontroller's program memory are usually referred to as "programmers".  This is the common way to get a program into a microcontroller.  This is also the only way to get a program into a blank or unprogrammed device.

For micros that are capable of writing to their own program memory, it is possible to put a specific program into the micro (using a programmer as described above), that can read data from a serial port, SPI port, IIC, or any other interface you can implement on that micro and write that data into its program memory.  Such a program on the micro is sometimes referred to as a "bootloader".

There are some gotchas and restrictions with bootloaders.  First and most obvious, the bootloader has to be written to program memory initially by regular programming.  Then you have to make sure the bootloader doesn't overwrite itself, or that the new program written by the bootloader doesn't have a bug so that the bootloader can't be run anymore to upload a fix, etc.  It can get tricky.  The bootloader will also require some resources, which needs to be taken into account in designing the applications the bootloader will upload.  You have to think about communication errors very carefully, since that could lead to corrupted code.  There are lots of schemes.  Bootloaders may be conceptually simple, but there are a lot more to them when you look at the details.

It is also possible for the program in the micro to act as a interpreter.  That means the high level program code is in a different language which the interpreter interprets on the fly and executes.  The high level code could be stored externally in a large memory.  The big drawback is that overall execution is much slower than when running natively.  This is why interpreters are rarely used for real projects.

Most of the time, you write code to natively run on the micro, write that into the micro with a programmer, then run it.  That's the simple and easy way.  Unless there is a good reason not to do it this way, that's what you should do.

Comment: Excellent answer in terms of the bootloader, I like how you give a good overall explanation yet also point out some of the nitty gritty details. Could you provide similar explanation of the interpreter. I am significantly less familiar with that approach and I suspect others are as well.

Comment: @Nick: A interpreter is basically a program prtending to be a processor.  It reads opcodes and executes them just like a real processor, but does it in software.  The interpreted instruction set therefore can be anything you can make up, regardless of what the instruction set of the underlying machine is.  Java "byte code" and a similar layer at the bottom of .NET are common examples.  In a micro, the interpreted code can be stored externally, like in a large EEPROM or flash.  The main drawback is that this is much slower than native code.

Comment: So to implement something like this the basic approach would be to have some sort of bootloader interface which allows the user to load the opcodes for the interpreter into whatever space it's going to be stored in. Then when that process is complete, the native code would basically read each opcode and pass it into a massive switch statement written in native code (the interpreter) which would then execute a bunch of native instructions for each interpreted opcode+parameter instruction. That about right?

Comment: @Nick: Yes ----

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You need a kind of script interpreter.
Google for the LUA language, it is very lightweight, has been ported to some MCU.

You may need to write some glue code to allow a user to upload its program, but the interpreter is here.